# Android font size in pt

Tags: android, android-fonts

I'm working on a Android project where I need to build my layouts based on a JSON layout file. This same file is also being used on an iOS app. So there is 1 file which will render the same layout on the Android as well as on the iOS.

The JSON layout file defines its font sizes based on the default iOS font unit.

From the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension):

> Points - 1/72 of an inch based on the physical size of the screen.

And as far as I can find, iOS font sizes are also defined as 1/72 of an inch.

So based on this info, I'd say the following should be enough:

```
view.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PT, fontSizeInIosUnit)
```

This however results in the text being too large. And it also seems to differ per device (which is weird since points should always appear in the same physical size).

Comment: Android has font settings, where you can select whether your font should be tiny, small, normal, large and huge. Maybe this is your problem?

Comment: @agamov this setting only affects sizes defined in SP

Answer (score -1):

If you want fonts to resize properly according to screen size you should use dp/dip instead.
So try this instead:

```
view.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, fontSizeInIosUnit);
```

Now this might not be exacly the same but in my experience this gives the best results. If it doesn't have the proper size then figure out what size you need on Android as the base size and then go with that instead.

Comment: no, you should use SP with fonts, DP for everything else.

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman yes and no. SP in an ideal world, but often you'll have a design where the text simply has to be fixed. To this answer, SP had properly been just as good.